# Drools logging below configuration level

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

I seem to be having some configuration issues with logback and drools.

```
<configuration scan="true">

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
             ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

    <logger name="org.drools" level="error"/>
    <logger name="org.optaplanner" level="info"/>
</configuration>
```

I don't want to see logs from drools yet I see several messages like these:

```
926  [main] INFO  o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl - Adding Service org.drools.core.io.impl.ResourceFactoryServiceImpl
927  [main] INFO  o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl - Adding Service org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.MarshallerProviderImpl
928  [main] INFO  o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl - Adding Service org.drools.core.concurrent.ExecutorProviderImpl
```

(and many more)

The messages are not shown if I configure my root to `error`. Any ideas how I can fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
<logger name="org.kie" level="error"/>
```